# prev->next for deleting a node not working in Visual Studio? Not showing any value in Debugger

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures

I am trying to debug my delete node function for a Linked List, but I am getting this error "-var-create: unable to create variable object" in Visual Studio. The error occurs when I try to set prev->next = current->next which is NULL.

```
node_t* delete_node(node_t* head) {
    // move through the head
    node_t* current = head;
    node_t* prev = NULL;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    prev->next = current->next;
    prev = current;

    // To free malloc space
    return current;
}
```

Here is what I am seeing in the debugger for Visual Studio:
[image]

What am I missing? Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the full Linked List code.

```
//Build the LL
struct node {
    struct node* next;
    char value[];
};

// set existing type, node, to the alias, node_t
typedef struct node node_t;

node_t* tmp1;
// declaring head pointer
node_t* head1 = NULL;


node_t* create_new_node(const char* value)
{
    // create space for node with malloc
    node_t* result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + strlen(value) + 1);
    if (result)
    {
        strcpy(result->value, value);
        result->next = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}

node_t* insert_at_head(node_t** head, node_t* node_to_insert) {

    node_to_insert->next = *head;
    *head = node_to_insert;
    return node_to_insert;
}

node_t* delete_node(node_t* head) {
    // move through the head
    node_t* current = head;
    node_t* prev = NULL;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    prev->next = current->next;
    prev = current;

    // To free malloc space
    return current;
}

//Get the Length of the Linked List storage
int get_length(node_t* head) {
    node_t* current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}

//Prints linked list
void printlist(node_t* head) {
    node_t* temporary = head;
    int count = 1;
    //Call get length function, if true continue, else call delete node function
    while (get_length > 5) {
        //delete node as space is full
        delete_node(head1);
        // free node here
    }

    while (temporary != NULL) {
        //print out the value of the node that temporary points to

        Log_Debug("%d. %s\n", count, temporary->value);
        // to move along the list
        temporary = temporary->next;
        count++;
    }
    Log_Debug("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: If the while loop fails in the first attempt itself then prev will be NULL and you are accessing prev->next. So this might be the cause. Once check it.

Comment: @SaiSreenivas current->next will always exist because I check it in a previous function. This function is only called when it reaches a length limit.

Comment: Okay once put the entire code. It will be easy to check

Comment: @SaiSreenivas I added the full LL code.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(*result)` should be `malloc(sizeof(result)`

Comment: `get_length > 5` - Well, that's not calling a function. Also, a print function that mutates what it's printing? That's just gonna end up increasing the rate of [wtf per minute](http://commadot.com/wtf-per-minute/)

Comment: How do you compile it ? Looks like a C++ error, strange to speak about object in C

Comment: @Ôrel - *"strange to speak about object in C"* The C standard makes use of the word over 1000 times. So you know... no that strange

Comment: @Ôrel why? Isn't result a pointer type?

Comment: To malloc an array of 3 char you do `malloc(3*sizeof(char));`

Comment: @Ôrel I see. That makes sense thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the comments above. It was a simple mistake. The get_length() function never had a value.

```
//Prints linked list
void printlist(node_t* head) {
    node_t* temporary = head;
    int count = 1;
    //Call get length function, if true continue, else call delete node function
    while (get_length(head1) > 5) {
        //delete node as space is full
        delete_node(head1);
        // free node here
    }

    while (temporary != NULL) {
        //print out the value of the node that temporary points to

        Log_Debug("%d. %s\n", count, temporary->value);
        // to move along the list
        temporary = temporary->next;
        count++;
    }
    Log_Debug("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```